# Understanding middleware in Express

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I am trying to figure out how middleware works in Express.

Whilst I understand the concept of middleware, I am confused by the middleware parameters.

Here is an example from [the offical docs regarding middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html):

```
app.use('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
   console.log('Request URL:', req.originalUrl)
   next()
    }, function (req, res, next) {
      console.log('Request Type:', req.method)
      next()
    })
```

In this example, I can see there are two functions that act as two middleware which are executed one after the other before this specific route is handled.

But what are the parameters passed to these functions?

Are `req` and `res` just "empty" objects?

If so how are we able to reference the property `req.originalUrl`?

And if not, where is that object and its properties coming from?

They also use `res.send` in the tutorial, so therefore the `res` object seems to also have properties and not be an "empty" object.

(I understand that `next` is a call back argument).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary**

The [request object](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) represents the HTTP request and has properties for the request query string, parameters, body, HTTP headers, and so on.

The [response object](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res) represents the HTTP response that an Express app sends when it gets an HTTP request.

[Middleware functions](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) are functions that have access to the request object, the response object, and the `next` function in the application’s request-response cycle. The `next` function is a function in the Express router which, when invoked, executes the middleware succeeding the current middleware.

Routes can have [chained methods](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) attached (for `GET`, `POST` and `DELETE` requests) that take middleware functions as arguments.

The request object is the data initially received from the request, which can be modified as it passes through various middleware functions, and the response object is the data sent out.

**Example Middleware**

Below is an example middleware function you can copy and paste at the beginning of your app:

```js
/**
 * An example of a middleware function that logs various values of the Express() request object.  
 * 
 * @constant  
 * @function  
 * @param  {object} req - The req object represents the HTTP request and has properties for the request query string, parameters, body, HTTP headers, and so on. In this documentation and by convention, the object is always referred to as req (and the HTTP response is res) but its actual name is determined by the parameters to the callback function in which you’re working.
 * @param  {object} res - The res object represents the HTTP response that an Express app sends when it gets an HTTP request.  In this documentation and by convention, the object is always referred to as res (and the HTTP request is req) but its actual name is determined by the parameters to the callback function in which you’re working.
 * @param  {Function} next - `next` is used as an argument in the middleware function, and subsequently invoked in the function with `next()`, to indicate the application should "move on" to the next piece of middleware defined in a route's chained method.  
 * @see {@link https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req|Express Request}  
 * @see {@link https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res|Express Response}  
 * @see {@link http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html|Writing Middleware}  
 */
const my_logger = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("req.headers: ");
    console.log(req.headers);
    console.log("req.originalUrl: " + req.originalUrl);
    console.log("req.path: " + req.path);
    console.log("req.hostname: " + req.hostname);
    console.log("req.query: " + JSON.stringify(req.query));
    console.log("req.route: " + JSON.stringify(req.route));
    console.log("req.secure: " + JSON.stringify(req.secure));
    console.log("req.ip: " + req.ip);
    console.log("req.method: " + req.method);
    console.log("req.params:");
    console.log(req.params);
    console.log("==========================");

    //if next() is not invoked below, app.use(myLogger) is the only middleware that will run and the app will hang
    next();

}

// called for all requests
app.use(my_logger);
```

**Example Routes**

Below are some example routes.

The routes have [chained methods](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) attached that take middleware functions as arguments.

```js
// some example routes
app.route("/api/:api_version/pages")
    .get(api_pages_get);

app.route("/api/:api_version/topics")
    .get(api_topics_get)
    .post(api_login_required, api_topics_post) 
    .delete(api_login_required, api_topics_delete);   

app.route("/api/:api_version/topics/ratings")
    .post(api_login_required, api_topics_ratings_post);
```

**Using `next()` in a middleware function**

In the above example, you can see some methods have two middleware functions as arguments.

The first one, `api_login_required`, verifies login credentials and, if successful, calls `next()` which prompts the next middleware function to run.

It looks like this:

```js
const api_login_required = (req, res, next) => {

    // req.user exists if the user's request was previously verified, it is produced elsewhere in the code   
    if (req.user) {
        next();
    } else {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized user!' });
    }
    
}
```

**Middleware without `next()`**

However, the `get()` method attached to the route handler for `/api/:api_version/pages` only has a single middleware function argument: `api_pages_get`.

As shown below, `api_pages_get`does not call `next()` because there are no middleware functions that are required to run after it.

It uses the [send()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) and [json()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json) methods of the response object to return a response.

```js
const api_pages_get = async (req, res) => {

    var page_title = req.query.page_title;

    var collection = mongo_client.db("pages").collection("pages");
    var query = { page_title: page_title };
    var options = { projection: { page_title: 1, page_html: 1 } };

    try {
        var page = await collection.findOne(query);

        // if there is no result
        if (page === null) {
            res.status(404).send('404:  that page does not exist');
            return;
        }
        // if there is a result
        else if (page !== null) {
            res.json(page);
            return;
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("api_pages_get() error: " + err);
        res.send(err);
        return;
    }

}
```

**Notes on middleware**

Some other notes I've previously written for my own reference that may help:

Middleware, or middleware functions, have access to the Express [request](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) and [response](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res) objects and are passed as arguments to a route's chained method (or on all requests if passed as an argument to an instance of the [use()](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use) method defined early in your code).

`next` is used as an argument in the middleware function, and subsequently invoked in the function with `next()`, to indicate the application should "move on" to the next piece of middleware defined in a route's chained method.

If a middleware function does not invoke `next()`, it will not move on to the next piece of middleware defined in a route or method handler.

Additionally, if `next()` is not used, and a terminating action, ie a response, is not defined in the function, the app will stay in a "hanging" state.

Answer (score 1):

> Do req and res are just "empty" objects?

No, `req` and `res` are never empty and are in fact same which are passed on to each middleware. You can also modify the `req` and `res` objects and the modification will persist in all next middlewares.

You can see all the available fields on `req` and `res` here respectively - [request object](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) and [response object](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res).

You can always access `req` and `res` at any point in a middleware. If you wish to the end the request response cycle, you can just use the response object and send a response like `res.send(200)`. This will end the req-res cycle and you need not call the `next()`.

> But what paramters are given to this functions ?

You don't need to pass any parameter to this function. Express will alwasy pass the `req`, `res` and `next` to any middleware defined. It's the format you can assume that express uses and and all middlewares should follow.

Note that if you don't end the req-res cycle, you must call the `next()` which will pass on the control to the next middleware. If the middleware does not end the req-res cycle and also does not call next(), the request will keep hanging and may perhaps just timeout on the client side.

Comment: Thanks. If they are not empty what exsits inside the req and res before I make any modifications to this objects ? What I can access and how do I know what I can access ?

Comment: @BenJ I edited the answer. You can follow the link which has all the available properties and methods on req and res object

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the confusing part are the objects passed to the middleware functions? In the docs you've linked there is already an explanation for those (See below).

- *"But what paramters are given to this functions ?."*

> Middleware functions are functions that have access to the **[request object (req)](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req)**, the **[response object (res)](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res)**, and the next middleware function in the application’s request-response cycle. The next middleware function is commonly denoted by a variable named next.

([Source](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html))

- *"Do req and res are just "empty" objects ?, if so how come we are using the field `req.orginaleUrl` ? and if not where is that object and
  its field came from ?"*

If you follow the links, you'll discover following explanation for the request object:

> The req object represents the HTTP request and has properties for the request query string, parameters, body, HTTP headers, and so on.

([Source](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req))

The `originalUrl` property mentioned in your question is a property of the `req` object.

and the response object:

> The res object represents the HTTP response that an Express app sends when it gets an HTTP request.

The `send` is a method assigned to the `res` object, which will send a HTTP response.

([Source](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res))